# When making a silo structured website is it ok to have header and footer on all pages?

Tags: seo, website-design, headers

When building a silo website from scratch, is it ok to include all the links in the header on any page? About, FAQ, Contact etc.

For those unknown: [What is the SILO Website Structure?](http://www.webuildyourblog.com/silo-website-structure/)

Comment: I do not know what you mean by silo. Can you help us out??

Comment: silo'ing each category so they do not cross contaminate any other category

Comment: I have read things on sites about silos, except it all seemed like total B.S. to me. Yes each category is a topic. Duh. But what is cross-contaminating and in the end what causal effect is there? I say none. I found the whole silo thing to be more SEO hog-wash and snake oil. Just make a site how you want to make a site and please ignore the SEO B.S. of which, the whole silo argument seems to be a classic example of.

Comment: Added a link to some documentation, let's learn something new

Comment: If topics on your website are so divergent that you can't even link between them for fear of confusing Google, you probably need two websites.     That being said, links between topics are fine as long as they are related.   Having a common author is often relationship enough.

Answer (score 1):

Silo best practice says to try and limit such links where possible.  If you need to keep the links, instead of having them in the header, move them to the footer.  The reason for that is the links near the top of the page are more valuable than footer links.

The other thing to remember is that the reader comes first.  If a link is appropriate, put a link.